# Update a different variable in the class with Java Lombok Builder

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I have the following class

```
@Builder
public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String device;
    private String deviceType;
}
```

I want to set the value `deviceType` based on the inputs I get for `device`. Is that possible with `Builder`? I don't want to set the value of `deviceType` directly.

Example

```
if (device == "iPhone") {
    this.deviceType = "mobile"
} else if (device == "Kindle") {
    this.deviceType = "tablet"
} .. and so on
```

Ideally, I want this to be done in the constructor one time

I am currently building the object like this but I am not sure how to initialize the `userEmail` field.

```
User.builder()
.userName("sample-username)
.email("sample-email")
.device("iPhone")
.build();
```

Comment: Why would you have separate `userEmail` and `email` properties?

Comment: It was just for example purpose, in my use case I have a class variable whose value would depend on one of these inputs

Comment: I updated the question with the real use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Lombok's [GetterLazy](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy)

From the doc,

> You can let lombok generate a getter which will calculate a value once, the first time this getter is called, and cache it from then on. [...] To use this feature, create a private final variable, initialize it with the expression that's expensive to run, and annotate your field with @Getter(lazy=true). The field will be hidden from the rest of your code, and the expression will be evaluated no more than once, when the getter is first called.

```
@Builder
private static class User {
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String device;
    @Getter(lazy=true)
    private final String deviceType = deriveDeviceType();

    private String deriveDeviceType() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(device);
        switch (device) {
            case "iPhone": return "mobile";
            case "Kindle": return "tablet";
            // and so on...
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid value set for device");
    }
}
```

With this, the `deviceType` field won't be available to be set via the builder.

Note that the field will be initialized *only* when the getter (`getDeviceType()`) is called and not when the field is accessed directly.

```
User u = User.builder()
            .userName("test-name")
            .email("test-email")
            .device("Kindle")
            .build();

System.out.println(user.getDeviceType()); //tablet
```

Since it is possible to pass an invalid value for device, I suggest you to look into using *enums* to model `device` and `deviceType` (if possible).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out! Yes, that field `userEmail`  was just for example purposes, my use case here is to assign a class variable based on other input variables. I want that class variable to not be initialized via the Builder

Comment: I updated the question with the actual use case and the variable I want to set

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.